# What is the difference between a direct argument and a global parameter, in a function?

Tags: javascript, arguments, global

What is the difference between a *direct argument* and a *global*, in a function?

By *direct argument* I mean to an argument we pass directly in function routine (instead in the subroutine based on parameters in the routine). For example:

```
var x = (0, 1)=>{ // Routine.
    // Subroutine.
}; // Routine.

x();
```

By a *global parameter* I mean to variables defined directly in the function's routine (edit, at least in JavaScript this is formally called ***global parameters***. For example:

```
var x = (x=0, y=1)=>{ // Routine.
    // Subroutine.
} // Routine.

x();
```

How will you explain the difference between direct arguments to globals?

<sub>Sorry if something was inaccurate in terminology.</sub>

Comment: The first code wont work.

Comment: Hi Jonas, I didn't mean it to have any special meaning. I used that only to display what I mean exactly by the term "direct parameters". Sorry for other impression.

Comment: Yeah but then your question makes no sense at all. How could we compare two things, when one does nkt exist in js at all?

Comment: The first is a syntax error, the latter isn't.

Comment: You mean it doesn't make sense at all in JavaScript or in programming @JonasW. ? I swear I've seen such example in some codes in the past, or I'm confusing something and having a great mistake in understanding the concept of "passing an argument directly not based on a parameter".

Comment: Jonas, let me aphasis, I didn't want to ask only on JS but in programming at all. Given I am not very familiar with any other language, I do wonder if this is applicable in any other language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes no sense at all :

```
let x = (0, 1)=>{ // Routine.
    // Subroutine.
}; // Routine.
x();
```

beacuse if you want to have predefined variables you just declare it in your function scope like so:

```
let x = () => {
    const one = 1;
    const two = 2;
}
```

A global variable is variable which you can access from anywhere in the program. In javascript you have the global object window. Global variables are in general bad practice. It would work like this:

```
one = 1;
two = 2;
let x = () => {
    // e.g. add one and two and return
    return window.one + window.two;
}
x();
```

Notice the that both variables declared don't have a const, let or var.

Since ES2015 you can supply default values for arguments:

```
let x = (x = 1, y = 2) => {
    // do stuff:
}
x();
// or
x(2, 3);
```

In this case if you call the function without declaring the parameters within the function call it will automatically be 1 for `x` and 2 for `y`

Comment: "predefine variables" → "supply default values for arguments"

Comment: @Quentin thx, I was actually struggling forming that sentence.

Comment: Just a note: I know the issue of global scope and function scope... I just meant to say I knew (and I was wrong) that 1 and 2 in `let x = (x = 1, y = 2) => {}` are named "globals". How are they named than?

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/default_parameters) default parameters

Comment: @Arcticooling Maybe you need to clarify your question when it's still not clear.

Answer (score -1):

*direct arguments* are not supported in javascript. Execute following code and you will see.

```js
let x = (0, 1)=>{ // Routine.
    // Subroutine.
}; // Routine.

x();
```